# How to extract phrases with word limit after specific Word?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have the following text, and I want to extract 5 words after a specific word from a string vector:

```
my_text <- "The World Cup 2022 winners, Argentina, have failed to dislodge Brazil from the top of the Fifa men’s world rankings as England remains fifth in the post-Qatar standings.
Had Argentina won the final within 90 minutes, they would have taken the top spot from Brazil. In the last eight tournaments going back to USA 94, no team leading the rankings at kick-off has won the tournament, with only Brazil, the 1998 finalists, getting beyond the quarter-finals."

my_teams <- tolower(c("Brazil", "Argentina"))
```

I want to extract the next 5 words after the word `Brazil` or `Argentina` and then combine them as an entire string.

I have used the following script to get the exact word, but not the phrases after a specific word:

```
pattern <- paste(my_teams, collapse = "|")

v <- unlist(str_extract_all(tolower(my_text), pattern))

paste(v, collapse=' ')
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the expected result `[1] "from the top of the won the final within 90"`?

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew.

Comment: Hi @bobblebubble. Overlapping is fine. If the word at the end, we start from the `.` then. It's up to 5 words. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
my_text <- "The World Cup 2022 winners, Argentina, have failed to dislodge Brazil from the top of the Fifa men’s world rankings as England remain fifth in the post-Qatar standings.
Had Argentina won the final within 90 minutes, they would have taken the top spot from Brazil. In the last eight tournaments going back to USA 94, no team leading the rankings at kick-off has won the tournament, with only Brazil, the 1998 finalists, getting beyond the quarter-finals."
my_teams <- tolower(c("Brazil", "Argentina"))
pattern <- paste0("(?i)\\b(?:", paste(my_teams, collapse = "|"), ")\\s+(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){4})")
res <- lapply(str_match_all(my_text, pattern), function (m) m[,2])
v <- unlist(res)
paste(v, collapse=' ')
# => [1] "from the top of the won the final within 90"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/81mzER). You can also check the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLfLfG/1). Note the use of `str_match_all` that keeps the captured texts.

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:Brazil|Argentina)` - one of the countries
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S+(?:\s+\S+){4})` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespaces and then four repetitions of one or more whitespaces followed with one or more non-whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you again @wiktor-stribizew. Much appreciated. It works perfectly. I have an extended doubt -- I have seen, for my pattern till 2nd match is enough. If I want till the 2nd match and them combine them, not all the matches, then what would be the right approach?

Comment: @Roy Sorry, that is not clear. If you want to `paste` only several items, use indexing.

Comment: Hi @wiktor-stribizew, it seems I can't a book session on codementor

Comment: @Roy Why not ask a question on SO?

Comment: One more doubt @wiktor-stribizew. If I also want to extract the word `brazil/argentina` and then the next 5 words, how should I approach?

Comment: @Roy That is exactly what the solution does. `(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+){4})` captures 5 words after the search word.

Comment: I mean I also want to add the team `brazil` or `argentina` along with the next 5 words, ie `search word + next 5 words` @wiktor-stribizew

Comment: @Roy It is even easier, use `str_extract_all` and remove - if you want - the capturing paremtheses. See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/4BvrUc).

Comment: Thank you so much @wiktor-stribizew. Much appreciated. When we use `str_extract_all` for this specific example, it returns 3 phrases and then we combine them. What if, we would like to keep only those phrases where the word `fifa` is present and then combine?

Comment: @Roy There are [only two matches](https://regex101.com/r/GydhDO/1). If you mean the word you want to require must be within those 5 words after the country name, [here is a working example](https://ideone.com/Bn2Z3r).

Comment: Yes @wiktor-stribizew, there are 2 matches, and I want to combine and return as a text

Answer (score 5):

Maybe not the best possible, but:

Split into a vector of words, remove non-word characters, lowercase (to match targets):

```r
words <- strsplit(my_text,'\\s', perl= TRUE)[[1]] |>
    gsub(pattern = "\\W", replacement = "", perl = TRUE) |>
    tolower()
```

Find locations of targets, get strings, paste back together:

```r
loc <- which(words %in% my_teams)
sapply(loc, \(i) words[(i+1):(i+5)], simplify= FALSE) |>
    sapply(paste, collapse=" ")
```

```r
[1] "have failed to dislodge brazil"    "from the top of the"              
[3] "won the final within 90"           "in the last eight tournaments"    
[5] "the 1998 finalists getting beyond"
```

Maybe you need one more `paste(., collapse = " ")` at the end ?

Comment: Thank you @Ben-Bolker for such a great explanation. `loc <- which(words %in% my_teams)` a nice trick. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative approach:

1. transform vector to tibble
2. use `separate_rows` to get one word in row
3. create helper `x` with lower case word
4. make groups starting with `brazil` or `argentina`
5. remove group == 0
6. get word 2 to 6 in each group
7. finale summarise:

```
my_teams <- tolower(c("Brazil", "Argentina"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble(my_text = my_text) %>% 
  separate_rows(my_text, sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(x = tolower(my_text)) %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(grepl(paste(my_teams, collapse = "|"), x))) %>% 
  filter(group > 0) %>% 
  slice(2:6) %>% 
  summarise(x = paste(my_text, collapse = " "))
```

```
 group x                                 
  <int> <chr>                             
1     1 have failed to dislodge           
2     2 from the top of the               
3     3 won the final within 90           
4     4 In the last eight tournaments     
5     5 the 1998 finalists, getting beyond
```